# Disable HTTP OPTIONS, TRACE, HEAD, COPY and UNLOCK methods in IIS

Tags: iis, web-config

For security reasons I want to disable those methods through application level
so I have this `web.config` file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <location path="index.php">
    <system.webServer>
                <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="TRACE" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="HEAD" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="PROPFIND" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="COPY" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="LOCK" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="UNLOCK" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="PROPPATCH" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="MKCOL" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="MOVE" users="*" />
            <deny verbs="DELETE" users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>

  </location>
</configuration>
```

But this didn't work - any ideas?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Finaly I found another answer for this problem. and this is working for me. Just add below datas to the your webconfig file.

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
     <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
    </verbs>
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Form more information, you can visit this web site: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering

if you want to test your web site, is it working or not... You can use "**HttpRequester**" mozilla firefox plugin. for this plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/

Comment: Another way to test this is to run a good web scanner against your site (you should do this anyway). If OPTIONS is enabled, it should pick it up.

Comment: Interesting. With IIS 7.5 I started getting 500.19 errors when I added the lines you mention. Looks like it is conflicting with my applicationHost.config settings.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me but only after forcing the specific verbs to be handled by the default handler.

```
<system.web>
...
  <httpHandlers>
  ... 
    <add path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
    <add path="*" verb="TRACE" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
    <add path="*" verb="HEAD" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
```

You still use the same configuration as you have above, but also force the verbs to be handled with the default handler and validated. Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1311323.aspx

An easy way to test is just to deny GET and see if your site loads.

Comment: even after using your code it does not work me. Can you please suggest what i could be missing. my evnironment is asp.net and IIS

Comment: @Ram Without seeing your config or having any knowledge of your environment I cannot suggest anything. Please as a question on SO and reference this question with more detail about your current setup.

Comment: I am getting HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error..! @BrutalDev, do you have any idea about this situation..

Comment: @MahmutEFE An internal error is unrelated to this question. 500 errors is usually something wrong in your code or configuration, I would start by checking the event log (Event Viewer) for ASP.NET runtime errors to determine what the actual underlying problem is.

Comment: @brutalDev thanks for your reply. When i apply your solution to the my web config, i got this error. After that i deleted it, the error gone.. But i found another answer. and my answer is below and working for me.. thanks again..

Answer (score 5):

This one disables all bogus verbs and only allows GET and POST

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
    <clear/>
    <add verb="GET" allowed="true"/>
    <add verb="POST" allowed="true"/>
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a UI option using IIS Manager.

1. Open the Website in IIS Manager
2. Go To **Request Filtering** and open the Request Filtering Window.
3. Go to **Verbs** Tab and Add HTTP Verbs to "Allow Verb..." or "Deny Verb...".
   This allow to add the HTTP Verbs in the 
   "Deny Verb.." Collection.

**Request Filtering Window in IIS Manager**
[image: Request Filtering Window in IIS Manager]

**Add Verb... or Deny Verb...**
[image]