# Removing / hiding the Http Headers

Tags: asp.net, post, http-headers

By referring the below forum

[Removing/Hiding/Disabling excessive HTTP response headers in Azure/IIS7 without UrlScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803972/removing-hiding-disabling-excessive-http-response-headers-in-azure-iis7-without)

I could easily hide the http headers like server information but still i'm getting below informtaion.

Is there a possibility to hide Allow and Public methods in the headers? Please share

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
**Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST**
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 09:37:00 GMT
**Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST**
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: What was the request that triggered this response?

Comment: OPTIONS /Main.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.com
Content-Length: 2

Comment: Returning which methods are allowed on the given resource is the sole purpose of the OPTIONS request. If you remove those headers from that response, the response becomes meaningless.

Comment: @CodeCaster the above request gives the response...IS there any way to do?

Comment: If that so... it is okay... we need to avoid others to analyze our server..

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comments, you **don't want to remove those headers from a response to an `OPTIONS` request**, because that request asks the server what other methods can be called on the given resource, in this case `/Main.aspx`.

The response contains the allowed methods in the `Allow` and `Public` headers. If you remove those headers, the response becomes meaningless.

If you want to disable the OPTIONS request altogether, see [Disable HTTP OPTIONS, TRACE, HEAD, COPY and UNLOCK methods in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131266/disable-options-trace-head-copy-and-unlock-methods-using-web-config).

Comment: will they Block POST option because i need this verb.... i don't want explicitly declare that our system uses POST and allows. Please give me clarity on this...

Comment: Will who do what now?

Comment: And I didn't understand yours. :-) What do you mean? If you click the link, you see you can disable specicic verbs, so you can prevent only the `OPTIONS` request to be processed altogether.

Comment: by adding these in config?  <add path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
    <add path="*" verb="TRACE" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
    <add path="*" verb="HEAD" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>

Comment: That config forces the verbs or methods `OPTIONS`, `TRACE` and `HEAD` to run through the default HTTP handler. Then you also need         `<deny verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />` (and other verbs you want to disable) in the `authorization` section in `system.web`.

Comment: I added this in config it throws me 500 internal server error why?       <authorization>
   <deny verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />
  </authorization>
  <httpHandlers>
   <add path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
   <add path="*" verb="TRACE" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
   <add path="*" verb="HEAD" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
  </httpHandlers>

Comment: 500 server error has been resolved but still option method is allowed!!! i could see the response with Allow and Public                    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 12:25:10 GMT
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

Answer (score -1):

Headers should be hidden anyway... Not quite sure what's happening here. Have you refreshed the main reference file.