# how to enable only GET & POST HTTP method in asp.net

Tags: http-method

I would like to have only `GET & POST` methods enabled in my application. 
How I need to add the code for the same in web.config file ???

```
<add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
```

this is the code that i have in my web.config file

Comment: <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    this is the code that i have in my web.config file

Comment: edit your question and add code.

Comment: <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />

Comment: the above comment is part of my web.config file

Comment: I had edit your question and I insert the code, but maybe you should clarify the question

Comment: i just want that only GET & POST Methods should be enabled , rest of the HTTP Methods should be disabled .

Comment: try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131266/disable-http-options-trace-head-copy-and-unlock-methods-in-iis but if don't write your appliction language is impossibile to help you.