# how to disable insecure http methods(OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE)

Tags: iis-8, http-put, requestfiltering

I have an web application hosted in IIS 8.5. I would like to disable the insecure http methods(OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE).
so to check if the method is disabled or not I am using burp suite.

I have disabled by navigating to Requestfiltering-> HTTPVerbs ->DenyVerbs and added PUT and DELETE in IIS.

when I tried using PUT method in burp suite, it was showing HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.404 - File or directory not found.
my expectation was if a HTTP method is disabled and when we try the method using burpsuite it should be displaying "405 Method Not Allowed".

Comment: where can i find the http error substatus?

Comment: hi i found the error sub status in IIS logs.2017-09-27 13:27:13 53656454764 OPTIONS / - 443 - 54435435435 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10.12;+rv:55.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/55.0 https://blahblahhdhskh.com 404 6 0 155.  the last number  404 and sub status 6 indicates the verbs were denied

Answer (score 0):

**You need to make these settings in the web.config file.**

```
<system.web>
...
  <httpHandlers>
  ... 
    <add path="*" verb="OPTIONS" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
    <add path="*" verb="TRACE" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
    <add path="*" verb="HEAD" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
```

[For more information, look at the BrutalDev's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585548/3870428)