# A preferred way to check if asp.net web application is in debug mode during runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

During compile time I can do a check like

```
#if DEBUG
    Log("something");
#endif
```

But what would be the preferred to check if `debug="false"` is set in Web.config during runtime?

Comment: When you run the project using Visual studio IDE , then it will ask to modify the web.config file to enable debugging.

Comment: Why don't you open the web.config file and look for it?

Comment: The idea is to check once it's been released, that's why the runtime check is important. Sometimes I want to enable debugging in production to get a detailed log of some actions, so if the production server is in debugging mode, it would vomit megabytes of log, but when I disable it it would do normal logging. I realize I can do this with log4net levels as well, but this way I can dynamically create JS files and enable Ajax logging of detailed JavaScript trace messages too! I DON'T want to ajax request to log something just to have log4net ignore it due to level :)

Comment: @AlbertoLeón I want the check to be programmatical for fine grained logging checks that I code into files - I will not change code in production.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled

Answer (score 60):

In some cases, you may need `HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled` (sort of obvious, but nonetheless)

Comment: I needed to do this today. Perhaps the two answers here should be merged into one? You'll need to use HttpContext.Current if you're in a static method. I'm not sure of the cases when HttpContext by itself is valid.

Comment: @BryanRayner: When you're in a controller, there's often a property available called HttpContext.

Answer (score 3):

There's another, non-programmatic external and empirical way to check if you've accidentally left the `debug=true` attribute on `system.web/compilation` on a Asp.Net website, i.e. to detect if you've left this configuration on in web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="xxx"/>
```

By using a tool such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), you can intercept a GET request to your web site, and then change this so that to [issue a non-Standard `DEBUG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2244703/314291) HTTP Verb to the site, along with an extra `Command: stop-debug` Header.

- Select a GET request to your site and drag it into the Composer
- Switch to the `Raw` tab (since DEBUG isn't a standard HTTP verb option)
- Edit the Verb from `GET` to `DEBUG`
- Add an extra `Command: stop-debug` Header (above the Cookies), but leave the rest of the Headers and Cookies in place
- Execute the `DEBUG` command

If the Web site returns 200 and the content `OK`, then you know you've left debug on. The web site will return `403 - Forbidden` if `debug` is off.

[image: Fiddler Screenshot]

If you've got your website building on a CI/CD build pipeline, best way to turn debug off is to add the following [XDT in your `Web.Release.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations#disable-debug-mode)

```
<system.web>
  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
</system.web>
```

(Turning debug off in Production is a common security audit requirement)