# Throwing an exception only when project is in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, exception

I am developing an ASP.NET web forms application. I have many functions that throw some exception on some particular situation. But there are a lot of functions. I don't want to remove and add `throw ex;` statement again and again when updating my application. So, is there any way I can check if the project is in debug mode? (i.e. to check if `debug="true"` in web.config).

```
try{
     //some code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     if(//----what condition to check debug mode?----)
         throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357490/a-preferred-way-to-check-if-asp-net-web-application-is-in-debug-mode-during-runt

Comment: You should never do `throw ex` inside a catch block; this destroys the stack information. Just use `throw;` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `#if` compiler directive:

```
#if(DEBUG)
/// do your thing
#endif
```

Comment: An alternative is using the  [Conditional("DEBUG")] attribute that you can set on a method that throws internally an exception. The compiler checks the conditional attribute and if you are NOT in debug mode, the method call is removed entierly from MSIL.

Comment: @GeorgeLica definitely cleaner, though it should be kept in mind that it would apply to a whole method... You could have a method that takes an action delegate with that attribute applied. Would make things even more cleaner

Comment: Very elegant! Very nice! That's why i love programming, it is like art: endless possibilities and endless styles to shape your code